# Cannot create /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, shell, python, cache, postgresql

I am using python because i try to run some queries from psql in cold state in a for loop.So before the execution of every query my cache must be clear.I imported os and then i did this:

```
if state=="cold"
     os.system('sudo sh -c  "/usr/bin/echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches')
```

Do you know how i can clear my cache using python?

I am using ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

Why Python and not shell? Running a shell command in python doesn't really make sense, if you really want to use Python you can do something like

```
with open("/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches", "w") as f:
    f.write("1")
```

and run the python script with `sudo` instead of trying to use it inside the script.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am using python because i try to run some queries from psql in cold state in a for loop.So before the execution of every query my cache must be clear!

Answer (score -1):

Try

```py
os.system('echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer..I tried it and i get this output:sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper.What should i do now?

Comment: Works here just fine in Fedora 33. Also I solved your initial problem - there's no need to downvote me. Lastly you can use `screen` in front of `sudo` as a workaround.

Comment: I didnt downvote you!Ok i will try that also.Thank you for your help!